# SQL Server : Select without some word

Tags: sql-server, select, procedure

I have a procedure like this;

```
SET @Oldname = (SELECT name 
                FROM [Marketing].[dbo].[_Users] 
                WHERE ID = @MID);
```

Everything is okay but some members got xxx, xxx_A1,xxx_A2,xxx_A3, while selecting these members I want to select without _A1 , _A2 , A_30

How can I select it?

Comment: Google splitstring function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reversing string, find first index of `_` and apply substring:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'John_Smith_234'

DECLARE @t TABLE ( Name NVARCHAR(50) )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'John_Smith_234' ),
        ( 'Michael_Jordan' ),
        ( 'Honore_De_Balzak_234' )

SELECT  SUBSTRING(Name, 1, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(Name))) AS Name
FROM    @t
```

Output:

```
Name
John_Smith
Michael
Honore_De_Balzak
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select left(name, len(name)-charindex('_', reverse(name))) name 
from whatever
```

Answer (score -1):

Assure that you add a '%' sign to your @MID Variable, looking like 'xxx%'

Than SELECT with LIKE instead of = :

```
SET @Oldname = (SELECT name From [Marketing].[dbo].[_Users] Where ID LIKE @MID);
```

I think you may also add the '%' sign in qour query (haven't tried):

```
SET @Oldname = (SELECT name From [Marketing].[dbo].[_Users] Where ID LIKE @MID+'%');
```

Comment: :) I want to select without  "_154" or like this.

Comment: Sorry, I think I have misunderstood something ;-)

xxx, xxx_A1,xxx_A2,xxx_A3 are values for the "name" column you select, and you want to get them without the chars after the '_' ?

So name is 'xxx_A1' and your select should return 'xxx' for name? 

Or am I still wrong :-o

Comment: @Helmut Some member names like "John_Sm_3 or xxx_xxx_xxx_test5" I want to select till last "_" so. I want to select only "John_Sm" or "xxx_xxx_xxx". Thanks :)

Comment: OK, it seems I understood now ;-)
I have seen that your question is already answered, using CHARINDEX, REVERSE and LEN of the string.